# BootstrapTable don't work pagination

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-table

I want use BootstrapTable extension but not config pagination.

```
$('#table').bootstrapTable({
    data: data,
    oprions :
            {
      pagination: true,
      pageNumber: 2,
      pageSize: 3,
      pageList: [2, 25, 50, 100]
        }
});
```

Options just not apply http://jsfiddle.net/3ev13xoc/  Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table options should come during your `bootstrapTable` declaration and without the object you have it in so it looks like this:

```
$(function () {
    $('#table').bootstrapTable({
        data: data,
        pagination: true,
        pageNumber: 2,
        pageSize: 3,
        pageList: [2, 25, 50, 100]
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eapannk6/